# IIS 6 windows 2003 86x ASP.net 2.0 site with asp.net 4.0 sub folder slow performance

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, asp.net, website, application-pools

I have an Windows 2003 server with an IIS 6 website running on it. recently we have had a component developed in .NET4.0 and installed in a sub folder to the website. A new App Pool was created for .NET 4.0 and the app Pool was assigned to the .NET 4 sub folder. I might need to mention that the original website uses both .NET 2.0 an legacy-asp. The site is running with Integrated authentication Against AD.

Everything is running except the integration to the .NET 4.0 folder. When the application in the .NET 4.0 folder is called it takes at least 15 seconds for IIS to serve the Page. Regardless of whether it is the first request or the 100th request. The .NET 4.0 application is called from a Legacy ASP form with a Frame showing the ASP.NET 4.0 application.

We cannot touch the Legacy asp or ASP.NET 2.0 application as we do not own the rights to the software IE only have a usage license.

Any ideas on how to speed Things up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to speed things up, you first need to understand what's slowing it down.  Obvious statement, I know, but you're going to have to analyse what's going on first.

In a situation like this, and I find myself making this suggestion all the time, you need to download and run Microsoft's SysInternals Process Monitor tool (procmon.exe).

Run it on the IIS box, and set a filter to only watch w3wp.exe.  Ensure you set the "drop filtered events" option.  Clear the log, carry out a (slow) transaction, and then stop monitoring.

Have a scan through the log, and try to identify what sort of activity is going on.  Use the Relative Time and Duration columns to build an idea of what's happening and how long it's taking.  Sometimes things are immediately obvious, for example, lots of time spent scanning for an .EXE or .DLL in the path, or a missing registry entry.

It can take some time, but it's the only tool that I'm aware of that gives you the equivalent of a packet sniffer for the O/S.  Talking of packet sniffers, it might be worth doing a wireshark trace as well, just to confirm it's the web server taking the time.

Good luck.